# After OpenERP 7 upgrade "ERROR: relation "ir_model_constraint" does not exist"

Tags: odoo

I'd been using OpenERP 6 OK and decided to upgrade to version 7.

I downloaded openerp_7.0alpha-20121206-000102-1_all.deb from http://nightly.openerp.com/trunk/nightly/deb/ and installed it. Now when I browse to `http://localhost:8069` I can no longer select the database (because when there is one DB there is no reason to show the selector,) and after log in I get:

```
OpenERP Server Error
Client Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/web/http.py", line 195, in dispatch
    response["result"] = method(self, **self.params)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/web/controllers/main.py", line 833, in authenticate
    req.session.authenticate(db, login, password, env)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 113, in authenticate
    uid = self.proxy('common').authenticate(db, login, password, env)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 28, in proxy_method
    result = self.session.send(self.service_name, method, *args)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 101, in send
    raise xmlrpclib.Fault(openerp.tools.exception_to_unicode(e), formatted_info)


Server Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/addons/web/session.py", line 87, in send
    return openerp.netsvc.dispatch_rpc(service_name, method, args)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/netsvc.py", line 361, in dispatch_rpc
    result = ExportService.getService(service_name).dispatch(method, params)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 413, in dispatch
    return fn(*params)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/service/web_services.py", line 424, in exp_authenticate
    res_users = pooler.get_pool(db).get('res.users')
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/pooler.py", line 50, in get_pool
    return get_db_and_pool(db_name, force_demo, status, update_module)[1]
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/pooler.py", line 33, in get_db_and_pool
    registry = RegistryManager.get(db_name, force_demo, status, update_module, pooljobs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 156, in get
    update_module, pooljobs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 178, in new
    openerp.modules.load_modules(registry.db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 296, in load_modules
    loaded_modules, processed_modules = load_module_graph(cr, graph, status, perform_checks=(not update_module), report=report)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 164, in load_module_graph
    init_module_models(cr, package.name, models)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/modules/module.py", line 373, in init_module_models
    result = obj._auto_init(cr, {'module': module_name})
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 3211, in _auto_init
    self._add_sql_constraints(cr)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 3350, in _add_sql_constraints
    self._save_constraint(cr, conname, 'u')
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 2859, in _save_constraint
    """, (constraint_name, self._module))
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/sql_db.py", line 162, in wrapper
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/sql_db.py", line 227, in execute
    res = self._obj.execute(query, params)
ProgrammingError: relation "ir_model_constraint" does not exist
LINE 2:             SELECT 1 FROM ir_model_constraint, ir_module_mod...
                                  ^
```

So I try to run it manually like:

```
sudo openerp-server stop
su - openerp
openerp-server -d openerp1 -u all
```

and I get

```
2012-12-07 07:00:43,417 7584 ERROR openerp1 openerp: Failed to initialize database `openerp1`.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/cli/server.py", line 97, in preload_registry
    db, registry = openerp.pooler.get_db_and_pool(dbname, update_module=openerp.tools.config['init'] or openerp.tools.config['update'], pooljobs=False)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/pooler.py", line 33, in get_db_and_pool
    registry = RegistryManager.get(db_name, force_demo, status, update_module, pooljobs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 156, in get
    update_module, pooljobs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/modules/registry.py", line 178, in new
    openerp.modules.load_modules(registry.db, force_demo, status, update_module)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 296, in load_modules
    loaded_modules, processed_modules = load_module_graph(cr, graph, status, perform_checks=(not update_module), report=report)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/modules/loading.py", line 164, in load_module_graph
    init_module_models(cr, package.name, models)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/modules/module.py", line 373, in init_module_models
    result = obj._auto_init(cr, {'module': module_name})
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 3211, in _auto_init
    self._add_sql_constraints(cr)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 3350, in _add_sql_constraints
    self._save_constraint(cr, conname, 'u')
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/osv/orm.py", line 2859, in _save_constraint
    """, (constraint_name, self._module))
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/sql_db.py", line 162, in wrapper
    return f(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/openerp/sql_db.py", line 227, in execute
    res = self._obj.execute(query, params)
ProgrammingError: relation "ir_model_constraint" does not exist
LINE 2:             SELECT 1 FROM ir_model_constraint, ir_module_mod...
```

What can I do, or should I have done to upgrade?

Comment: Creating a new database works fine. But, how do I get my version 6 data into the new DB?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no free upgrade mechanism from OpenERP 6.0 to 7.0 for now. OpenERP SA makes a living by selling a commercial upgrade solution, for which you get a considerable discount if you have a yearly support contract with them.

Using -u all will probably attempt to upgrade you database schema, but il will not migrate your data (i.e. if a column was renamed, you will not get your data moved from the old column to the new one), and the views will not be migrated either : the new views with the same XML ids  replace the old ones, new views are created, and old views are still there, possibly referencing fields which no longer exist. Basically your DB is now a total mess, and hopefully you have a backup which you can use to continue running v 6.0.

Comment: I thought that since I'd made no changes to OpenERP upgrading 6.1 to 7.0 might be automatic. Thanks Alex; it wasn't clear to me that "openerp-server -d db -u all" only works on minor version upgrades. I appreciate your candor!

Comment: @DaleE.Moore unfortunately, this is not the case for major upgrades. There are some community efforts to build such a tool (and it exists for the 5->6 migration. Development has started for 7, but it will take time to support all the modules.

Answer (score 2):

Did you have installed V6.1 too in the same machine?

This error happend when you have mixed old version modules and new ones.

I recommend install a Virtual Machine and try again on it, if im right, you ca unistall the package, delete all files (modules) related to the package and re-install.

If you need to repair database to old version, re-instal 6.1 or 6.0 and bring up your server with parameters -u all -d nameofdb.

Regards.

Comment: I only had V6.1; sorry that my OP was misleading! 

I hadn't thought of downgrading; thanks! That's a good idea.

Once I get back to a functional previous-version; what would you suggest as the most successful upgrade procedure?

Comment: Do you have a preferred upgrade path? APT, BZR, or DEB?

Comment: I am suspicious that this might be typical with my early use of this new version. In another instance I get:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools-0.6c12dev_r88846-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 565, in resolve
    while requirements:
pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: openerp==7.0alpha